# How can i solve getApplicationContext() java.lang.NullPointerExeception

Tags: java, android, azure-mobile-services, android-applicationinfo

I am trying to connect to an **azure** application, using **android**, but I am getting this error. Here is my code and my logs.

I have checked everything and it seen to be right, but the problem I think is with `getApplicationContext()`. I am unable to debug.

can someone help me please?

```
public class login extends Activity {

    UserServicesImpl usv;
    private EditText txtemail;
    private EditText txtpassword;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        txtemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        txtpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    }

    public void LoginKarrega(View view){

                usv = new UserServicesImpl();

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(login.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");

                if(usv.exist(txtemail.getText().toString(), txtpassword.getText().toString()) == true) {
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Sucessful login");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                }
                else {
                    alertDialog.setMessage("wrong login");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                }

                alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:105)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.notifications.MobileServicePush.<init>(MobileServicePush.java:134)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.initialize(MobileServiceClient.java:1473)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.<init>(MobileServiceClient.java:182)
            at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient.<init>(MobileServiceClient.java:158)
            at ao.co.karrega.services.customers.UserServicesImpl.<init>(UserServicesImpl.java:39)
            at ao.co.karrega.login.LoginKarrega(login.java:32)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Post your LogCat outputs

Comment: Post your LogCat trace please...

Comment: I posted already man. please help me

Comment: why @Pooja ? I am showing the activity and the log, what else do you need ?

Comment: Where is the code where you trying to get `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Are you sure error is in this class, I am to able to see the use of getApplicationContext any where in the code..

Comment: Ya thats the point @Pooja I don't have it in my all code but it is saying that on the logs

Comment: @keshav1234 I have edited the code can you take a look again please ?

Comment: @Keshav1234 it is a class that connect to the azure mobile application, retrieve the data from the data base that is associated with the application mobile, and has a method exist to check if the email and password passed matches with any record on the database

Comment: where is your button on which you are calling LoginKarrega() check out is this correct in your xml

Comment: Yes @Prashant Bhoir, the button on the xml has this android:onClick="LoginKarrega"

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to solve this error. Currently you are using this instead of getApplicationContext().

```
try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "https://newvbdemo.azure-mobile.net/",
                "SUFYiOYEAlbEoKfsDgfWNIywaPSMhC29",
                getApplicationContext()

        );
        mTable = mClient.getTable("Users",Users.class);
    }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `UserServicesImpl extends Activity` but it does not seem to be an `Activity`.

In particular, activities usually don't have an explicit constructor, and you cannot use an `Activity` as a `Context` before its `onCreate()` lifecycle method. Construction phase `<init>` in your stacktrace is too early.

The stacktrace also shows that you're trying to instantiate an activity with `new` in `LoginKarrega`. Never instantiate an activity with `new` yourself.

Looks like you should be removing the `extends Activity` and pass a `Context` as an argument instead.

Comment: Mr. @laalto I have updated it can you take a look again please?